# ScrapyD with Django stops running after sometime

Tags: python, django, cron, scrapy, scrapyd

I have a whole django(2.2) application with scrapyd deployed on the production server.
It seems to work fine but I noticed a trend recently that the crawler just stops running after some days. 
 I run the scrapyD server using cronjobs.

- When the server restarts, a .sh file runs.
- Using `nohup` command:

  - This script activates the venv and starts the scrapyd server using `scrapyd` command.

Then using management controls, I run the crawler which scrapes the website and stores data in a MySQL database. The scraping works fine for 3 days as I can see the debug logs but then it doesn't run i.e there are no new logs generated in logs directory of scrapyd.

I then ran the management control manually to see what is the issue.
 An exception is raised
when scrapyd.schedule() is called:

> File
>   "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapyd_api/wrapper.py",
>   line 188, in schedule
>       json = self.client.post(url, data=data, timeout=self.timeout)
>
> File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
>   line 581, in post
>       return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
>
> File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapyd_api/client.py",
>   line 38, in request
>       return self._handle_response(response)
>
> File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapyd_api/client.py",
>   line 34, in _handle_response
>       raise ScrapydResponseError(json['message'])
>
> scrapyd_api.exceptions.ScrapydResponseError: attempt to write a
>   readonly database

I have gone through some answers where people recommended to set the permissions. This is not that, the permissions of my directory are set and the scraper runs for some days.

I restart the production server by `sudo reboot`

The scraper runs again for some days and then mysteriously stops again with the same issue.

I am using MySQL for database.
Ubuntu is the server of Digital Ocean.

I have another scrapyd server deployed which runs through the same process but it's only running and not used. The ports of these two servers are different so I don't think there is a clash.

Any help would be appreciated because restarting the production server over and over again seems very unreasonable.
I saw a similar question and it is close to what I am experiencing:

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/295

Comment: your script is failing to write to the scrapyD's SQLITE DB file

Comment: I don't have the sqlite db file in any directory and secondly I am using MySQL. I don't understand even if I need sqlite db file then why?

Comment: scrapyD uses a SQlite db file to manage jobs data

Comment: and where exactly should it be if I am using a venv?

Comment: `DIRECTORY_WHERE_YOU_RAN_SCRAPYD_FROM/dbs/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.db`

Comment: The permissions for the dbs folder and the file default.db are set to www-data:www-data already. Also its strange that it runs for some schedule() calls and then mysteriously stops. If it doesnt have permission to write, why does it runs in the beginning?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206285/discussion-between-umair-and-fahad-rana).